# A sequence $u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots$ is defined by $u_n=10 \times 0.6^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> A sequence $u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots$ is defined by $u_n=10 \times 0.6^n$. Find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$$

What is required of the question? i think that this question is a Infinitely sequence, so i need your help to answer this smart question

thanks for all people work in this useful web site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the geometric series 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n u^i= \frac{u^{n+1}-1}{u-1}$$
and try to write your sum in one of those

As you have 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 10 \cdot 0.6^n -10 = 10 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty 0.6^n-10= 10 \cdot \frac{1}{1-0.6}-10=10\cdot \frac{1}{0.4}-10=25-10=15$$

Comment: can we answer it by S∞ = a/1 – r

Comment: Brian M. Scott > thanks for nice editing ♥

Comment: @moamen you honestly confuse me a bit i don't know if you are trying to say the right things, parentheses would help a lot

Comment: @moamen: You’re welcome. (You can start learning how to do that kind of editing [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).) Yes, it’s $\frac{a}{1-r}$, where $a$ is the first term, and $r$ is the ratio of consecutive terms.

Comment: S∞ = a/1 – r                                                        a= 6 because 10*0.6^1 = 6  ---  r = 10*0.6^2 /10*0.6^1 = 0.6   so 6 /1-0.6 = 15    thanks   Brian M. Scott and    Dominic Michaeli  but the answer is 15 not 25 ??

Comment: @moamen: Not quite: your summation starts at $n=1$, so $a=u_1=10\cdot0.6=6$.

Comment: i thinks that the answer is 15 not 25

Comment: jupp sry i forgot the first term isn't in

Comment: Dominic Michaelis thank you for your help and editing ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥